# Makefile for a simple application

Tags: makefile, compilation, libxml2, gstreamer

I have a file app.c which uses two libraries GStreamer and libXml2. To compile the application I type the following on Terminal

```
gcc -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10) app.c -o app -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2
```

When I try to Makefile with the contents as follows :

```
all:
        gcc -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10) app.c -o app -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2
run:
        ./app
clean:
        rm app
```

On running make command I get the errors as expected. What is the significance of

```
$(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10)
```

on Echoing the above I get some files which when included in Makefile gives me the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pkg-config --cflags libraryX` outputs the path to the header files of libraryX.  Without this, the compiler does not know where to look for the header files, and compilation will fail.

Similarly, `pkg-config --libs libraryX` outputs the path to the actual compiled library files of `libraryX`.  Without this, the linker does not know where to look for the library files, and linking will fail.

`pkg-config --cflags --libs libraryX` is just combining what I described above.  Since you're using `gcc` to do both compilation and linking, you just pass those parameters together to `gcc`.

Comment: When I do xml2-config --cflags on my host machine I get the output  -I/usr/include/libxml2 as the output. But when I do so in a different processor (guest) I get the error xml-config not found though the libxml2 installed there. I want to complile the application for the guest from the host.

Comment: By "different processor", do you mean another username?  It's likely that the guest account doesn't have the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable set correctly.  Try doing `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` using both usernames and compare the results.

Comment: Also, be sure you are using `bash` shell (just type `bash` at your prompt to get into one).  The default shell for some distributions like Ubuntu is `dash`.  I just tried this in a `dash` shell and the command expansion (bit between the back-quotes) didn't get expanded correctly.